# Fuzzy logic t-norm

Tags: logic, normed-spaces, fuzzy-logic

I am trying to understand fuzzy logic. I got to t-norms and trying to do some exercises on them.

Can you explain to me how to make a t-norm of the following formulas and verify if they are tautologies:

**Lukasziewicz t-norm**

$(A \Rightarrow  B) \Rightarrow  ((B \Rightarrow  C) \Rightarrow (A\Rightarrow C))$

**Product t-norm**

$\neg\neg A\Rightarrow (((B\&A)\Rightarrow (C\&A))\Rightarrow (B\Rightarrow C))$

**Gödel t-norm**

$((A \Rightarrow  B) \Rightarrow C) \Rightarrow  (((B \Rightarrow  A) \Rightarrow C)\Rightarrow C)$

I am confused how to make them in correct way.
Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us what is $t$-norm?

Comment: T-norm or also known as triangular norm is a kind of binary operation used in the probabilistic metric spaces and in multi-valued logic, specifically in fuzzy logic.